# Universal Analytics goal not triggering after redirect from payment provider

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have set up a Tag for Purchase goal by destination in Google Tag Manager with RegEx. The RegEx matches the URL:

**RegEx:** /checkout/abo/done/\w+/?success=.+

**Thank you URL:** /checkout/abo/done/123456789abcd/?success=1&kind=abo&online=1&period=1

The Tag is set up as an event, sending data to Google Analytics.

However as the user pays online is being send to a payment provider and redirected back to the domain with this particular thank you page.
The flow looks like this:
site.com/checkout --> site.com/payment --> security.com --> site.com/thankyou

The problem is that the goal is not being triggered in Analytics and no datalayer is detected. The _gid stays the same, so the session itself should'n be a problem. And security.com is added to referral exclusion list.

What could be the problem and how can I find a proper solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
/checkout/abo/done/\w+/?success=.+
Your Regex is missing the escpaing.

https://regex101.com/